# Auth-0 Multiple connections Login

Tags: auth0

We are trying to login using auth0 using native form way by hitting /oauth/token end point and using password flow.
There are multiple connections created and we have a requirement to allow login to work for any user in any connection. Is it possible to get the token without passing connections? Currently Auth0 is saying realm is required and not passed to Auth0 api.
Is there any setting in Auth0 such that it checks in all the connections for the user id (email) and password we pass.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean you have multiple username password databases connections for a single application, auth0 will simply pick the first available database and try to authenticate the user. It's good practise to limit to one database connection per application. I would recommend either merging the databases or use a separate login application for each database so you can have only one database connection enabled per client.

If it's crucial that you need to have multiple database connections active for a single application, I guess you could loop through the database and try authenticating in each one although that will obviously be quite slow. I don't believe Auth0 provides any support out of box for concurrently  authenticating with multiple databases.